# Can ng-model be attached to a style tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I wanted to create a basic template editor using angularjs, I wanted to know is it possible to create an input field with an ng-model, and connect that variable to a style tag to control the css on an the entire page instead of using it on a particular element with an in-line style? is it possible to do something like this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body { height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }    
            div, ul, li, ol, span { margin:0; padding:0; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea type="text" ng-model="data.style" placeholder="enter style"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
<script>

    window.addEventListener('load', function(){

        var style = document.createElement('style');
        var textnode = document.createTextNode('{{data.style}}');
        style.appendChild(textnode);

        document.querySelector('head').appendChild(style);


    }, false)

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but you have to be aware of the limitations. Something like this is fine:

```
  <head>
    <style ng-bind="myStyle"></style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Type Style Here</h1>
    <textarea ng-model="myStyle"></textarea>
  </body>
```

But something like this is not:

```
<head>
  <style>
   h1 { 
      background-color: {{color}}
   } 
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Type Background Color Here</h1>
  <input ng-model="color" /> 
</body>
```

If you do want to be able to interpolate styles like this last example, you would have to do the interpolation somewhere else (in your controller perhaps, and then bind the final interpolated strings. The reason "{{color}}" won't work is that it will try to add illegal html nodes inside the style since it assumes it is in html and not css.

Here is a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PoRKwfBI9MtnakHvUU7Y?p=preview

Comment: I did it and it worked with the css but for some reason its evaluating the html as a string literal when I type it in, if I for example if I type in <div> my output section show <div> as the text it doesn't evaluate variable in the model as markup is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You have to use ng-bind-html directive for that.

Comment: I was searching and it was saying on here that you use ngSanitize, but I tried the ng-bind-html it didn't work do I have to create a module or is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: IF you are using versions of angular prior to 1.2.x you can use ng-bind-html-unsafe. If you are using angular 1.2.0 or above you us ng-bind-html and use the $sce stuff to mark your content as safe. This is doucmented here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce  If you can provide a sample plunkr with what you are trying to do, it will be easier to help you achieve it.

Comment: OK I will do that I use js bin but I can create a plunkr account.

Answer (score 1):

You can load an entire style sheet on demand like so:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.4" data-semver="1.2.4" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="{{styleHref()}}" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <div class="box"></div>
    <textarea ng-model="data.style"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    ]).
    controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {
      $scope.data = { style: "style-1" }; // can come from init func, http call, etc
      $scope.styleHref = function() { return $scope.data.style + ".css"; };
    });
```

See [this plunkr as an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZsMEwQ7MmJav4rTjLQ6?p=preview)